# Need help in Reading contents of memory array and get a count in vhdl

Tags: process, vhdl

input array: Ram = {D D D D D 3 3 3 3 7 7 7 9 9 8 8};
I am expecting the output as below:

Count = {0 0 0 4 0 0 0 3 2 2 0 0 0 5 0 0};

That is to count the number of occurances, like there are five D's , four 3's , three 7's, two 9's and two 8's so that Count array has 5 in Dth index, 4 in 3rd index, 3 in 7th index and so on.

my code is as below:

```
 architecture behav of Bitcount is
   signal cnt: count_type := (others=> (others=>'0'));
   use ieee.numeric_std.all;

  begin 
  Countproc:process(clk) 
  begin
   if (clk'event and clk='1' ) then
    if Enable='1' then
       if (Read_bit='1') then
           for k in 0 to 15 loop
              for i in 0 to 15 loop
                if ( Ram(k) = std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, 4)) )then         
                  cnt(i) <= cnt(i) + "01";
                end if;
              end loop;
        end loop;
      end if;
   end if;
   Count <= cnt;
  end if;
end process Countproc;
end behav;
```

[image: wave]
but its not working as my expectation . pls help

Comment: You ought to explain what is actually happened. You should also give an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Too many type conversions (and no declarations in the example ... see MCVE) ... pick your types better and it'll simplify, probably allowing you to see the bug.

Comment: I am trying the count the number of occurances of each content of input memory array. and count_type used above is -     type count_type is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `cnt` is a *signal*. It needs to be a *variable*.

The lines of code within a process are executed *sequentially*. Whenever a line of code containing a *signal assignment* (`<=`) is executed, an event is put on the event queue to drive the target signal (`cnt` in this case) on the next delta cycle (assuming there is some change to the target signal as a result). The event queue is the simulator's "to do" list; a delta cycle is one iteration of the simulator; the next iteration will occur once all the processes that are executing in the current iteration suspend.

If, during any execution of a process, another signal assignment to the same target signal is encountered, then (usually*) any other events on the event queue relating to that signal are deleted. So, in your example, every time this line is encountered (which it will be 16*16=256 times):

```
cnt(i) <= cnt(i) + "01";
```

Instead of incrementing `cnt(i)` (which is what I assume you are expecting to happen), all previous events relating to `cnt(i)` are deleted and replaced with a new event to drive `cnt(i)` with *the value it had before the process started executing* plus one. The signal `cnt(i)` does not get its new value until the process completes executed (and all other processes too).

Variables do not exhibit this behaviour; variables behave just like variables do in any software language. When a line of code is encountered with a *variable assignment* (`:=`), the variable is updated immediately and so its value is immediately available for further calculations.

So, how about changing `cnt` to a variable:

```
architecture behav of Bitcount is
  use ieee.numeric_std.all;
begin 
  Countproc:process(clk) 
    variable cnt : count_type;
  begin
    if (clk'event and clk='1' ) then
      if Enable='1' then
        if (Read_bit='1') then
          cnt := (others=> (others=>'0'));
          for k in 0 to 15 loop
            for i in 0 to 15 loop
              if ( Ram(k) = std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i, 4)) )then         
                cnt (i) := cnt (i) + "01";
              end if;
            end loop;
          end loop;
          Count <= cnt;
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process Countproc;
end behav;
```

I can't be sure this will work, because you haven't provided an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I haven't tested it. But you original solution will not work for the reason I have given.

--

* this is nearly always true, because of the way that VHDL models delays as *inertial delays* and it is certainly true in this example. But strictly it's not always true.

Comment: @ matthew Taylor, your answer is exactly correct. i was using a signal instead of variable. I got the output as per the my requirement. Can i ask you what else you were expecting from me to provide in the question (entity as well)? I am new here , so wanted to learn things.

Comment: As I said, your question could be improved by adding 2 things: i) a description of how your circuit was actually behaving (the waveform wasn't clear) and (more importantly) an MCVE. With an MCVE, anyone can execute your code and reprodecue your problem. To turn your example into an MCVE you would have to add (i) the entity, (ii) the descriptions of the types you have used and (iii) a simple testbench.