# Can't increment in VHDL while loop

Tags: loops, vhdl, 32-bit, divider

I want to make an easy program that would subtract one 32 bit number from another and count the number of subtractions with the help of a while loop (so basicly makes a divide between the two numbers). I'm using this code:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity divider_32bit is
    Port (  O1: in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
            O2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
            clk : in STD_LOGIC;
            Result : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
            Remain : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end divider_32bit;

architecture Behavioral of divider_32bit is

signal res : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := X"00000000";

signal temp : unsigned(31 downto 0);
signal temp2 : unsigned(31 downto 0);

begin

temp <= unsigned(O1);
temp2 <= unsigned(O2);

 Result <= res;
division: process(clk)

begin

    if(rising_edge(clk)) then

        while temp >= temp2 loop

            temp<=temp-temp2;
            res<=res+1;

        end loop;   

    end if;
end process division;

end Behavioral;
```

My problem with this code is I can't make the res incerement, it remains as it was initialized (0). 
I experienced with it, and i found out that if I remove the while loop it starts to behave normally. So I had to mess up something with it, but as I am a beginner I can't really tell what's wrong with it. 
I only want to make a simulation for it.

Comment: You need to find out how VHDL signals behave. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696983/need-help-in-reading-contents-of-memory-array-and-get-a-count-in-vhdl/42698193#42698193) is an explanation. They don't behave like variables. You need to make `res` a variable.

Comment: Thanks! What about temp and temp2? Can I use them for the while loop's argument?

Comment: No. For the same reason.